# Пусть у меня фронт на одном сервере, бэк на другом. Как бы мне это корректно организовать?

Tags: http, frontend, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер, backend

У меня есть два варианта реализации веб-приложения:

1. Есть сервер, где работает бэкенд. Отдельно есть сервер, где лежит фронт. При этом, этот сервер, где фронт, он, как бы, просто хостит дист джаваскриптового приложения как статику. Я имею в виду, что там нет никакого серверного кода. Пусть это будет какой-нибудь nginx например. Само джавоскриптовое приложение ходит на сервер бека за данными. На сервере бека настроены Cors. Короче говоря, хостимся на одном хосте, а за данными ходим на другой. Прям из браузера.
2. Второй вариант подразумевает тоже два сервера. Но во втором варианте запросы с фронта идут на сервер фронта, который в свою очередь проксирует все на сервер бека.

Прошу описать, какие преимущества/недостатки есть у того и другого подхода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы рискнул сказать, что второй подход в плане применения является доминирующим.
Его преимущества: Он очен прост. Проксирование настраивается в nginx довольно элементарно. Кроме того, Вы сразу получаете кеширование GET - запросов и кучу других плюшек, в котрых nginx действительно хорош - таких, как SSL - сертификаты на фронте, сжатие трафика на фронте и т.п. При этом бэк может быть очень "глупым" и не бояться этого: плохие запросы от злобных хакеров к нему всё равно не придут, фронт отфильтрует. А в ряде случаев фронт прячут ещё и за клоудфлером каким нибудь.

Собственно, единственным преимуществом перврго подхода можно назвать относительную - относительную! - независимость фронта и бэка. Всё остальное при таком подходе - это исчезновение тех преимуществ, которые я описал в первом параграфе.

Как говорил Иа-Иа - "по моему, так". Еще кто то что то добавит?

Comment: соглашусь с этим мнением и добавлю, что проксировать через nginx можно и другие вещи, например, на модный по нынешним временам mqtt. Плюшки в виде распределения нагрузки или холодного старта. Вариант предпочтителен на мой взгляд

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! По поводу того, добавить ли еще что-то, да, если несложно. А что если я планирую активно работать с веб-сокетами? Не будет ли второй способ иметь ограничений?

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak о каком виде ограничений идет речь. Из опыта: я работал с упомянутым выше mqtt протоколом через веб-сокеты плюс SSL. Никаких серьезных проблем не повстречал. На уровне реализации, точно.